# Re-render Angular2 component when property is not changed

Tags: javascript, angular, zone

I have case with Angular2+ when I need to re-render component without model change.

I try

```
ApplicationRef.tick() ,NgZone.run(callback),ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()--
```

not success

Is there a way to re-render the markup of the component if the model has not changed?

Comment: Why and when do you need to do that?

Comment: I have the logic in component for calculating the location on the page. And when the browser resizes, I need to re-apply this logic

Comment: I would like to understand more about your use case. It seems that you might be trying to do layout yourself that would be better left up to CSS. if you do want to capture a resize event and handle some specializied re-layout logic, that's easy enough to do, by simply updating properties which will automatically re-render the component via normal change detection. Perhaps if you could show a bit of your code we could help more.

Comment: This can not be done through css.I update question

Comment: just use a host listener:
@HostListener('window:resize')
doWhatever(){...

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is just a suggestion of a workaround/hack, as your use case is one that is difficult to match in the world of Angular (where state defines everything and change in state triggers events).

Why not have a model that reflects the number of times the window was resized? There is no need to have it visible on the website, as having it even in a hidden element will also cause the component to repaint.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'zomg',
   template: `<span style="display:none;">{{resized}}</span>`
})
class Clss {
    resized: number = 0;

    constructor() {
      const _self = this;
      window.onresize = () => {
        _self.resized++;
      };
    }
}
```

or alternatively by using a [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener):

```
@Component({
   selector: 'zomg',
   template: `<span style="display:none;">{{resized}}</span>`
})
class Clss {
    resized: number = 0;

    @HostListener('window:resize')
    onWindowResize() {
        this.resized++;
    }
}
```